# How do you get a JavaScript object definition to give custom output in the console?

Tags: javascript

I noticed this the other day for the first time while checking out the "CamanJS" project. This question is difficult to explain unless you just do it. If you go to camanjs.com, then using either Firebug or the Chrome JavaScript console, type in the word `Caman` and press enter. Not  `Caman()` with parentheses -- just `Caman`. It will output: `Version 4.1.0, Released 2/12/2013`.

But if you look at `typeof Caman`, it's just a "function." So how on earth do you get it to output a custom string like that, without actually calling the function? Is that done through some sort of `prototype` extension?

Comment: Another interesting "native" property is `valueOf`: `var x = function () {}; x.valueOf = function () {return 5;}; // x + 3 === 8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would happen if the function has a custom `toString()` method.

For example:

```
function x() { }
x.toString = function() { return "Hi there!"; };  
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Interestingly, the return of `toString` is used as the object's name even if you use `console.dir` (tested in Chrome)